# ThreeJS doesn't update vertex position in shader

Tags: three.js, shader

I have a sphere and I'm trying to increment it in vertex shader multiplying his vertices by a constant, but the default attribute `position` from threeJS doesn't update.

```
uniform float extraSize;

void main(void) {
    vec3 newPosition = position + extraSize*normal;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
}
```

When I multipy it by `extraSize` variable, the sphere changes but `position` and `model.geometry.vertices` doesn't it.

I have already in my code `model.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true` and `modelGeometry.dynamic = true`.

This is an example code of my problem:
[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/meji/su0bxsk1/)

Comment: Changing the vertex position in the shader does not change it in the javascript object

Comment: And there are any way to modify vertex in the shader with respect to its last position?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "last position". bjorke's answer explains my comment better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in the shader does not trickle back to THREE's javascript-based vertex list. You'll need to directly manipulate the members of your mesh's `geometry.vertices` if you want persistent changes.

Also, while this will scale a sphere okay, consider what might happen if you scale along normals on a more complex object -- you will get scaling in varying directions, essentially inflating/deflating the shape. Maybe that is what you want?

For a simple scale operation, what's wrong with using the mesh scale method?

Comment: I'm exactly trying to do is this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/meji/qvkses95/) but with permanent changes. I'm trying to do it in the shader because do it in javascript is very slow, but if you say that for persistent changes I should manipulate the `geometry.vertices` in javascript, I can't do it in the shaders :( .